# Bad vertical alignment in latex \tabular

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I've got a little question about my tabular vertical aligment. I've a two-column tabular with letter and text :

```
\begin{tabular}{p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.8\textwidth} }

Hypothèse   &   Description\\
\hline
```

But in my pdf file, the first and second column is not aligned. I tried to align everything to the top, to insert space with \\[1ex], but nothing seems to work!

[image: My Example of not aligned text]

In fact, the problem seems to come from the counter I use to enumerate the letters :

```
\newcounter{hypothese}
\renewcommand\thehypothese{\Alph{hypothese}}
\newcommand{\newhypothese}[1]{\refstepcounter{hypothese}\label{#1} \ref{#1}}

\footnotesize


\begin{tabular}{p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.8\textwidth} }

Hypothèse   &   Description\\
\hline
\hspace{1pc}&\

\multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth}}{\textbf{Multimodalité}} \\
A & Bla bla Bla blaBla blaBla blaBla blaBla blaBla blaBla blaBla blaBla blaBla bla Bla bla Bla bla\\
B &Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
C& Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla  \\
D& Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
% Upon here, everything looks right... below here, first column are not aligned right.
\newhypothese{hypo:cla_ver} &Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:com_acc_recoup} & Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:reg_negoc} & Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:reg_croise} & LBla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:gest_reg_part} & Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:gest_verba} & Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:trace_graph_verba} & Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \
```

But I don't know how to fix it

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx. Can you provide a complete MWE.

Comment: @cacamailg : Here's part of my code that mess things up : http://pastebin.com/6hzpwNhv

Comment: It would be better if you build a MWE herein, for us to test your code. Nevertheless, why are you using `\hspace{1pc}` after the `tabular`.

Comment: Also you are using a `multicolumn` of `\textwidth` after you have defined two columns, one of `0.1\textwidth` and other of `0.8\textwidth`. Which is not a good practice.

Comment: I used it \hspace to add vertical space below my \hline.

Comment: I tried to make a MWE of the "bug" i try to fix, but i can't replicate it - when i just copy and paste my code in another document, it looks right.

Answer (score 2):

You can profit from the `tabularx` package, so you don't have to fiddle with the subtle points of the interaction between issuing `\label` and printing `\thehypothese`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\newcounter{hypothese}
\renewcommand\thehypothese{\Alph{hypothese}}
\newcommand{\newhypothese}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{hypothese}\label{#1}\thehypothese}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
Hypothèse   &   Description\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Multimodalité}} \\
\newhypothese{hypo:cla_ver} &New hypothese: Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:com_acc_recoup} & Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:reg_negoc} & Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:reg_croise} & LBla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:gest_reg_part} & Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:gest_verba} & Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:trace_graph_verba} & Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to come from this command not starting with any printing material.  In particular, `\label` uses internal commands `\@bsphack` and `\@espack` which successfully gobble the correct number of spaces before and after when the command is in ordinary text, i.e. horizontal mode, but which do not necessarily do the right thing in between paragraphs, i.e. in vertical mode.  (See [`source2e` pages 52--53](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/source2e) for a discussion of possible modifications of these commands.)  In many situtations, including your case, you can fix this simply by forcing horizontal mode via `\leavevmode`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{hypothese}
\renewcommand\thehypothese{\Alph{hypothese}}
\newcommand{\newhypothese}[1]{\leavevmode\refstepcounter{hypothese}\label{#1}\ref{#1}}

\begin{tabular}{p{0.1\textwidth} p{0.8\textwidth} }
Hypothèse   &   Description\\
\hline
\hspace{1pc}&\\
\multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth}}{\textbf{Multimodalité}} \\
A &Ordinary label: Bla bla Bla blaBla blaBla blaBla blaBla blaBla blaBla blaBla blaBla blaBla bla Bla bla Bla bla\\
B &Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:cla_ver} &New hypothese: Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:com_acc_recoup} & Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:reg_negoc} & Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:reg_croise} & LBla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:gest_reg_part} & Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:gest_verba} & Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\newhypothese{hypo:trace_graph_verba} & Bla bla Bla bla Bla bla \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The solution I found below seems to work for now, but i'll look at yours if it turns out it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. By juste replacing

```
\newcommand{\newhypothese}[1]{\refstepcounter{hypothese}\label{#1} \ref{#1}}
```

by

```
\newcommand{\newhypothese}[1]{\refstepcounter{hypothese}\thehypothese\label{#1}}
```

It looks perfect... I don't know why.
Thanks anyway

Comment: That doesn't work, as your labels are no longer defined, and your label is now doubled.  Deleting the `.aux` file and compiling again will give you problems...

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad... I replaced the line by 
     \newcommand{\newhypothese}[1]{\refstepcounter{hypothese}\thehypothese \label{#1}}

Comment: OK - I have updated my answer accordingly with some explanation.  Your rewriting introduces printed material before the `\label` so the `\label` command is now in horizontal mode.